# Operation "read-attribute" failed during JBoss EAP 7 startup

Tags: jboss, wildfly

I have deployed my application on JBoss EAP 7 in SSL mode.
My application gets deployed and runs successfully but during start up, 
I get following error on console every time when server starts up and WAR is simultaneously deployed, no exception is thrown.

```
11:28:11,402 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 92) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("read-attribute") failed - address: ([
    ("subsystem" => "undertow"),
    ("server" => "default-server"),
    ("https-listener" => "defaultssl")
]) - failure description: "WFLYCTL0216: Management resource '[(\"subsystem\" => \"undertow\")]' not found"
```

I have been searching **Red Hat JBoss Knowledgebase**, but have not found any solution to this issue.

***This issue is not reproduced, if I deploy my WAR after the application server completely starts up and is initialised.***

**This issue does not affect my application though.**

This issue is not reproduced on JBoss EAP 6.x, JBoss AS 7.1.x and Wildfly.
What can be the reason of such issue?

Comment: how does your undertow subsystem configuration look like?

Comment: Does your application try to query undertow subsystem model during deploy?

Comment: Yes. I debugged my application and found it. At that time, it looks like the undertow module is not initialised and it shows error. I bypassed that code of my application and that error was not shown. As of now I have found workaround for the said issue and my application works fine. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I observed the behavior of the JBoss EAP 7 application server. The undertow subsystem is not loaded during the server initialization. This issue occurs when application tries to access the details of the undertow subsystem during startup. When the application is deployed after server has started this issue does not occur.